# How to use Conditional Rendering and Redux in App js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to implement authentication flow with Redux in my app, I am using conditional rendering in my App.js file to show either app screen or authentication screen.

App.js:

```
    <Provider store={store} >
      <NavigationContainer>
        {store.getState().auth.initializing && <Initializing />}
        {store.getState().auth.isLoggedIn && (
          <AppNavigator/>
        )}
        {!store.getState().auth.initializing &&
          !store.getState().auth.isLoggedIn && (
          <AuthenticationNavigator/>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
```

The problem is it doesn't react on changes in the state, when I press Login button on the login screen even though redux refreshes the state, the conditional rendering in App.js doesn't react anyhow and I still see login screen. If I use `useState` with isUserLoggedIn flag in the App.js, and pass callback to the components it works, but not with Redux.

Please help, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redux [`store.getState`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) is only a function that returns the current state, it doesn't subscribe to changes to the store object. This only works when the component rendering your conditionals is rerendered.

What you can do is either use the [`subscribe`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) method to subscribe to changes in the store, caching the state locally:

```
const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(() => store.getState().auth);

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    setAuth(store.getState().auth);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);

...

<NavigationContainer>
  {auth.initializing && <Initializing />}
  {auth.isLoggedIn && (
    <AppNavigator/>
  )}
  {!.auth.initializing &&
    !.auth.isLoggedIn && (
    <AuthenticationNavigator/>
  )}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Or you and use the [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) from `react-redux` to effectively do the same thing:

```
const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);

...

<NavigationContainer>
  {auth.initializing && <Initializing />}
  {auth.isLoggedIn && (
    <AppNavigator/>
  )}
  {!.auth.initializing &&
    !.auth.isLoggedIn && (
    <AuthenticationNavigator/>
  )}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Note that both of these solutions ***absolutely require*** the Redux store `Provider` to be moved higher in the ReactTree so that this component can consume the redux context and access the store's value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to wrap App.js in the Provider? Because looks like that useSelector doesn't work in current setup

Comment: @BorisMitioglov That is what my note at the end describes. Both solutions require pushing the Redux store `Provider` at least a level higher in the ReactTree, i.e. if `App` is the component rendering `NavigationContainer` then the Redux `Provider` needs to wrap `App`. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, I end up moving NavigationContainer into the separate component where I used mapToState hook, now it works, thanks for pointing me to the right direction ```<Provider store={store} >
      <MainNavigatorScreen/>
    </Provider>```